# How to export string with comma in the value in csv?

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I export the datagridview records in csv file using code :

```
using (StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.Default))
{
        string sHeaders = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
             if (dGV.Columns[j].Visible)
             {
                 sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText + ", "; 
             }
        }
        myFile.WriteLine(sHeaders);
        // Export data.  
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount; i++)
        {
             string stLine = "";
             for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
             {
                 if (dGV.Columns[j].Visible)
                 {
                     stLine = stLine.ToString() + dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ", ";
                 }
             }
                        myFile.WriteLine(stLine);
        }
     }
  }
```

But problem is if the value in the datagridviewcell is Harikrishna,Daxini then it will not exported properly,because there is comma in the cell value, but I have a need of including comma in the value.And it should export properly.How can I do that ? I tried with enclosing that value by double quotes and single quotes but it does not work.

Comment: Double quotes should have worked. Do you have spaces between a seperating comma and opening double quotes?

Comment: @Belinda, Like this - " Harikrishna,Daxini " ?

Comment: What I meant is are you typing your values like `"val1","val2"` or `"val1", "val2"`. This could make a difference with CSV.

Comment: @Belinda, I am writing like "val1", "val2".

Comment: Short version of my answer I think that the spaces are your issue. Remove them.

Comment: @Belinda,Great, It works now without space between a seperating comma and opening double quotes,I tried with enclosing that type of value in which there is comma, but it did not work, But now I tried with removing space between a seperating comma and opening double quotes and enclose that value with double quotes and it works.Great and thanks. How did you know that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spaces between seperating commas and an opening double quote can cause issues with CSV. Replace code like `"val1", "val2"` in your csv file with `"val1","val2"`. That should fix your issue.

Comment: I had no idea that spaces between the commas would matter like that.   This solved a problem that I had been struggling with and was difficult to even describle.

Answer (score 3):

Values that contain a ',' need to be escaped by surrounding them with double quotes.

```
         for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
         {
             if (dGV.Columns[j].Visible)
             {
                  var value = dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                  var append = value.Contains(",")
                                 ? string.Format("\"{0}\"", value)
                                 : value;
                  stLine = string.Format("{0}{1},", stLine, append) ;
             }
         }
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work like "\"" +|harikrishna,daxini + "\"".

Comment: @Harikrishna this is the correct way to export values with commas. How are you reading or consuming the csv that you generate? Maybe the code that is reading your csv does not properly parse quoted data fields?

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work, why I am checking but this does not work.

Comment: Only one problem is there that is there should not space before comma and it will work.